# Trying to create emails for staff using substr()

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Trying to combine a first name, a last name, and then concatenate with an email address ending. i.e. fname = John, lname = Smith, email portion is @PROP.com in OracleSQL developer

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTR(CONCAT(fname, lname),0,LENGTH(FNAME+1))
FROM
  STAFF;
```

Comment: Please add sample data.

Comment: Hi! its exactly as listed in the title, there is a table named staff, where the first persons name is fname = John, lname = White. If my code worked correctly it would result in JohnW@PROP.com.  Am i able to post snips of the data somehow?

Comment: I figured out the problem! my +1 after LENGTH(fname) should have been outside the parenthesis for it to work. Thank you Tim!

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```sql
SELECT fname, lname, fname || SUBSTR(lname, 1, 1) || '@PROP.com' AS email
FROM STAFF;
```

I suggest using `||` for multiple concatenations here as the `CONCAT()` function only accepts two parameters.